# Let $G$ a finite group with $H<G $ its only finite subgroup, then $H$ is normal subgroup of $G$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

> Let $G$ a finite group with $H<G $ its only finite subgroup, then $H$ is normal subgroup of $G$.

I'm try to do this, because the proposition uses a finite orders, I believe that use the Lagrange Theorem can be useful, but simply I can't dedice which definition of a normal subgroup can help me.

Any comment and help was very helpful for my in this moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if $H$ is the only subgroup of finite order then it must be the trivial group, and hence it is normal in $G$. So I'll assume you mean the only nontrivial subgroup of finite order.

Note that for each $g\in G$, the group $gHg^{-1}$ is a subgroup of $G$, and $|gHg^{-1}|=|H|$. Since by assumption there are no other subgroups of the same order we deduce that $gHg^{-1}=H$ for each $g\in G$.

Comment: Thanks that was very helpful, but also, I'm not so good using conjugation, you can recommend read some post about congution and improve my habilites to understand better group theory.

Comment: I think you can read about this in pretty much any book about group theory. Anyway, the definition is just $gHg^{-1}=\{ghg^{-1}: h\in H\}$.

Comment: I'm reading introduction to group theory of Joseph J. Roman, but really these lecture has been hard to Read and understand.

Comment: @BrienNavarro One way of looking at this is that because $H$ is the only subgroup with a particular property, it is [very often] a characteristic subgroup, and every characteristic subgroup is normal (essentially for the reason given in this answer - conjugation must preserve it, because it is the only one).

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Conjugation preserves the order of subgroups.

Comment: In these case the definition are $gHg^{-1}=H$?

Comment: Yes, @BrienNavarro; here $g$ ranges over all elements of $G$.

Comment: Thanks so much your comment helped my to understand better the definition.