# How to prove the order of $gKg^{-1}$ is the same as the order of $K$ given $K$ is a subgroup of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Given $K$ is the only subgroup of order $m$ of a group $G$ and to prove $K$ is normal.

I know that $gKg^{-1}$ is a subgroup of $G$.

I have reached that if order of $gKg^{-1}$ is the same as $K$ then $gKg^{-1}$ would equal $K$ as only one subgroup of order $m$ exist. But how to prove it ?

Comment: Hint:  show that conjugation is a bijection.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3859452/104041).

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Ohk by constructing a bijection from K to gKg$^{-1}$ there order would be same
Thanks